# A person at the origin on a 1 dimensional line must step k integer values in 1 direction to find a specified k. How can this be done in O(k) steps?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

A person stands at the origin of a 1 dimensional line. He is trying to get to a point that is k steps away in one direction. The direction is unknown and the distance is also unknown. How can this be done in O(k) steps.

I know the answer is probably something obvious but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: What is `n`? The distance from the frog to the magic lily pad?

Comment: Yes, n is the distance from the frog to the magic lily pad, but it is unknown.

Comment: I'm curious where you found this problem :-) Is it from a textbook?

Comment: Haha, its from a problem set my prof gave me

Answer (score 3):

The frog can hop (one pad at a time) to 1, -1, 2, -2, 4, -4, 8, -8, 16, -16 and so on. That is, the frog hops in one direction until she reaches a pad that's a never-before visited power of 2 away from the center and then starts hopping back the other way.

If the magic pad is at distance N from the center, the total number of hops will be at most 4(1+2+4+...+2^ceil(lg N)). That's 4(2^(1+ceil(lg N))-1) which is less than 16N.

Comment: Replacing your sequence with 1,-2,4,-8,16,... lets you replace 16 with 9. ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

The frog cannot go in one direction only or it might miss the magic lily pad; so it has to go in both directions.

The frog can only go so far in one direction before having to check the other; to cover the entire strip of lily pads it needs to go back and forth.

In one attempt, he will try to look at all lily pads at a distance less than `x` from his starting pad. He'll go `x` hops forward, `2x` backwards, and `x` forward again, having covered `2x` lily pads in `4x` hops.

Making an attempt of 1, then one of 2, then one of 3 etc. will lead to too many hops, covering only `n` lily pads in `O(n²)` hops.

However, if the attempted distances are an exponential series, there's a limit on how many failed attempts he'll do before finding the magic lily pad. If he attempts 1, then 2, then 4, then 8 etc. (`2^n`, works for larger bases as well), he'll cover `n` lily pads in `O(n)` hops.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) is defined as the maximum time-complexity, or the upper bound for completion.  If you have n lily pads in a row, a straight through traversal would take at maximum O(n) because each lily pad is visited once. The only issue would be, if the frog is placed somewhere in the middle of the row (not at one end), and the rows are infinite.  In that circumstance, you would need to determine which direction (left or right) to traverse the row and you have a chance of never finding the magic lily pad.  Also, infinite rows implies n approaches infinity (so O(n) could be an infinitely long period of time!).  I don't see an answer if the frog starts in the middle of an infinite set of rows that expand in both direction. If the frog starts at one end of an infinite set of rows, O(n) is achieved by hopping one lily pad at a time in the same direction.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not a computer scientist so my grasp of big-o is flakey. I first thought the same as you, then I second-guessed myself and thought that this interpretation was answering how to solve it in n hops, rather than order of n.  Now I'm not so sure again!

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I can find is to take n steps in a random direction, and if you don't end up at the magic pad, turn around and take 2n steps.  So worst-case is 3n steps. 3n is proportional to n - it grows linearly.  So O(n).

Comment: How would the frog know `n`?

Comment: Good point. When I answered the question it didn't mention that the frog doesn't know n. The question was subsequently edited.  Given the omission and the question title, I made the incorrect assumption that the frog knew.